# Status code 500 when I try to update a mongodb document

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

I'm getting a server side error: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500]. It's only clear that something is wrong in my request but not sure what it is.

The console error for this react-native app is pointing to the updateExpense function:
expenses-context.js:76:6

Call Stack

[image]
This is how data is moving between components:

ExpenseForm.js is where expenseData is constructed:

```
    async function submitHandler() {
        const expenseData = {
            amount: +inputs.amount.value,
            date: new Date(inputs.date.value),
            description: inputs.description.value,
            _id: inputs._id.value
        }
```

After that, expenseData is passed to the confirmHandler:

```
function confirmHandler(expenseData) {
        if (isEditing) {
            expensesCtx.updateExpense(_id, expenseData)
            console.log('expenseData', expenseData)
            navigation.goBack()
        } else {
            expensesCtx.addExpense(expenseData)
            navigation.goBack()
        }
```

and the output of console logging expenseData here is:

```
expenseData {"_id": "64e1aaad97da840a04ce64e5", "amount": 99.99, "date": 2023-08-19T00:00:00.000Z, "description": "Update Expense"}
```

then, updateExpense inside expenses-context.js takes _id and expenseData:

```
async function updateExpense(_id, expenseData) {
            try {
                await axios.put(`http://localhost:8082/expenses2/${_id}`, expenseData);
                dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE', payload: { _id: _id, data: expenseData } });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error updating expense:', error);
            }
        }
```

And finally, app.put is called in server.js and passed _id and expenseData:

```
await Expense.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId(_id) }, { $set: expenseData });
```

in the line above

```
app.put("/expenses2/:_id", async (req, res) => {
            const _id = req.params._id;

            try {
                // Update the expense in the database based on expenseId and req.body
                const expenseData = req.body
                await Expense.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(_id) }, { $set: { expenseData } });

                res.json({ message: 'Expense updated successfully' });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error updating expense:', error);
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while updating the expense' });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be happening because of the way you are using the $set operator in updateOne method in your route handler. You are setting the entire expenseData object as a field in your document. Instead, you should directly pass the expenseData object to $set.

```js
app.put("/expenses2/:_id", async (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params._id;

    try {
        // Update the expense in the database based on expenseId and req.body
        .....

        // Use the _id to update the specific expense
        await Expense.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(_id) }, { $set: expenseData });

        res.json({ message: 'Expense updated successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
       //... handle error
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks! I made that adjustment: { $set: expenseData }
but I am still getting 500 error.

Comment: Please add the error with your question. It is being logged in your server’s console.

Comment: Added the console error. It points to the updateExpense function.